# C# add Embedded Resources to project while running

Tags: c#, file

This is a weird question because i tought about it for some time and it doesnt really make sence to me because the program would need to re-compile, but, because if it is possible it would make my program much simpler, i need to know it there is a way to do it.
Basicly i have a `.exe` program.
The program has a combobox, that gets its value off a `.txt` file.
Its pretty simple to edit the values on the combobox, all the user has to do is to edit the `.txt` file and restart the program, but I need to make so that, if we move the `.exe` to another computer, it brings the `.txt` with him, so i added the `.txt` to my project.

The problem:
I need the user to, if needed, edit my `.txt` file.
If he edits the `.txt` file, it means i would have to update the file embedded in my `.exe` and from what i have searched, its not possible to do that.

My idea to solve this:
When the program starts, i copy the `.txt` out of the program, delete the embedded file on the project, and when the user closes my program, it copies the `.txt` that's on the outside, inside, like if i were to manually add it to the program again, that way if the user did edit it, if he moved the `.exe` to another computer, it would have its combobox values updated. It makes some sence to me, thats why im curious to see if it is possible, and if so, how do i add a external file to my project while it is running.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible - at least not in an easy way. You could edit the txt block of the exe file with an hex editor and save the edited exe, but your normal and advanced user will not know about that and I **strongly** advise against it. you could create a copy of the exe and create it next to it, so the user can edit it, but it will stay there. Alternatively you could make use of the folder `UserData` and save the file there (fixed location). But rewrite it back to your exe? Not easy or recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the other way around.

You can add an application configuration file and in that you can maintain the values for your `comboBox` inside `appSettings` section with comma separated values. During the load it will take from config and during closure of the application you just need to update the appSettings section with the updated value.

Code to update the configuration file:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings["comboKey"].Value = "comboValues with comma separated";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

When you are copying your application to some other system then you should copy the `app.exe.config` along with the `app.exe` file.

If you are trying with any installer file in different system and you would to have a user settings, then you could also use the `Settings.setting` file with User level scope variables.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of the use of settings, but we are talking about several diferent .txt's while alot of lines, meaning that manually write each line would be out of question and making a cycle for the program to write it would take too much time, and this program needs to run verry fast because it is used to handle a server database. Regardless, thanks for the awnser!